# How to use C3 charts in ember js

Tags: ember.js, charts

I need to create a web application using ember js.In which there is a need for c3 chart creation.could you please help me?thanks in advance.

Comment: check emberaddons.com, there appear to be a few wrappers created around c3 already (none rated too high though) http://www.emberaddons.com/?query=c3

Comment: Is there a specific need for using c3 chart? Another library you could use is called ZingChart which has a [wrapper](https://github.com/zingchart/ember-zingchart) for Ember applications along with a pretty easy [tutorial](http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2015/02/24/zingchart-ember-js/) to get you started

Comment: yes we have a specific need for using C3 chart

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a component, which will render a chart. Check an [ember documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/) to learn about components. [This post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks) from an official blog also should be useful, as it contains a description of new component hooks.